# How to bind collection dependency property in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, observablecollection

This is not a duplicate! When I failed I tried to look to similar posts but without success. I cannot understand why `OnUCItemsSourceChanged` is not called? I'm pretty sure that I miss something simple but I cannot find it.

I have `Window` that contains `UserControl1` which has attached collection property that is bound to `Window`'s `WindowCollection` collection. I expect `UserControl1.OnUCItemsSourceChanged` to be called when I add items to `WindowCollection`. But it doesn't happen.

What I miss?

**Window1.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<long> WindowCollection { get; set; }
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = this;

        WindowCollection = new ObservableCollection<long>();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WindowCollection.Add(1);
        WindowCollection.Add(2);
    }
}
```

**Window1.xaml**

```
<StackPanel>
    <uc:UserControl1 UCItemsSource="{Binding Path=WindowCollection}" />
    <Button Content="Refresh" Click="Button_Click" />
</StackPanel>
```

**UserControl1.xaml.cs**

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty UCItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("UCItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnUCItemsSourceChanged)));

public IEnumerable UCItemsSource
{
    get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(UCItemsSourceProperty ); }
    set { SetValue(UCItemsSourceProperty , value); }
}

public ObservableCollection<MyItem> UCItems { get; set; }

private static void OnUCItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = d as UserControl1;
    var items = e.NewValue as ObservableCollection<long>;

    foreach (var item in items)
   {
         control.UCItems.Add(new MyItem(item));
   }
}
```

**UserControl1.xaml**

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding UCItems}" ... />
```

**UPDATE**
This is [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_j2rCBlhOaNN0hrckpNVGEzNDg/edit?usp=sharing) to my test project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding UCItems}" ... />
```

Must be `RelativeSource` with FindAncestor, because *`UCItems`* located in UserControl:

`UserControl`

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UCItems,
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
```

---

> `I cannot understand why OnUCItemsSourceChanged is not called?`

If you add RelativeSource construction, then `OnUCItemsSourceChanged` causing at least once because [`PropertyChangedCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) triggered every time then you set new value for the dependency property:

> Represents the callback that is invoked when the effective property value of a dependency property changes.

Since you once sets the value for dependency property here:

```
<uc:UserControl1 UCItemsSource="{Binding Path=WindowCollection}" />
```

---

> `I expect UserControl1.OnUCItemsSourceChanged to be called when I add items to WindowCollection.`

For this is an [`ObservableCollection<T>.CollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event, in that contains the enumeration of acts performed on the collection:

> Occurs when an item is added, removed, changed, moved, or the entire list is refreshed.

For your case it will be something like this:

**`Version with CollectionChanged`**

`MainWindow`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<long> WindowCollection { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        WindowCollection = new ObservableCollection<long>();

        WindowCollection.Add(1);
        WindowCollection.Add(2);            
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WindowCollection.Add(3);
        WindowCollection.Add(4);
    }
}
```

`UserControl`

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    #region Public Section

    public ObservableCollection<long> UCItems { get; set; }
    public static UserControl1 control;

    #endregion

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        UCItems = new ObservableCollection<long>();            
    }

    #region UCItemsSource Property

    public static readonly DependencyProperty UCItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("UCItemsSource", 
                                                                                                  typeof(IEnumerable), 
                                                                                                  typeof(UserControl1),
                                                                                                  new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnUCItemsSourceChanged)));

    public IEnumerable UCItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(UCItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UCItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion

    private static void OnUCItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        control = d as UserControl1;
        var items = e.NewValue as ObservableCollection<long>;

        items.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(CollectionChanged);
        AddItem(control, items);
    }

    private static void CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var items = sender as ObservableCollection<long>;
        control.UCItems.Clear();

        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            AddItem(control, items);
        }
    }

    private static void AddItem(UserControl1 userControl, ObservableCollection<long> collection) 
    {
        if (collection.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in collection)
            {
                userControl.UCItems.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

> This project available in this [`link`](http://1drv.ms/1jJw1EH)

**`Alternative version`**

This version is simpler and more correct. Here we just reference to `UCItemsSource` property that contain collection, also here `RelativeSource` justified:

**`UserControl`**

`XAML`

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UCItemsSource, 
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                                       AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

`Code-behind`

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    #region Public Section

    public ObservableCollection<long> UCItems { get; set; }

    #endregion

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        UCItems = new ObservableCollection<long>();
    }

    #region UCItemsSource Property

    public static readonly DependencyProperty UCItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("UCItemsSource", 
                                                                                                  typeof(IEnumerable), 
                                                                                                  typeof(UserControl1));                                                                                                      

    public IEnumerable UCItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(UCItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UCItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I updated my post - `UCItems` is of type `ObservableCollection<MyItem>` and not `ObservableCollection<long>`. Anyway, why I need `RelativeSource` if `DataContext` of `UserControl` is `UserControl1`.

Comment: @theateist: `UCItems is of type ObservableCollection<MyItem> and not ObservableCollection<long>` - why do you not have this at once in your question? And what exactly does not work?

Comment: When I add items to `WindowCollection` they should be added to `UserControl1`'s `UCItems` collection which is bound to `ItemsControl.ItemsSource`. Very similar to how `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` works. I added link to my test project. I'll appreciate if you could take a look

Comment: @theateist: I looked at your example. Found a couple of notes. First, type in `ObservableCollection<T>` should be one. That is, or the all `Long` or `MyItem` types. In my case, in main Window Binding will not work then states different types. Secondly, the code in handler of `OnUCItemsSourceChanged` running only once, when the program starts. Until you assign a new collection, this handler does not call, therefore the collection will not be updated.

Comment: so, is there any way to do what I want to do - to pass collection of `long` to `UserControl1` and it should create out of them another collection which should bound to `ItemsControl.ItemsSource`?

Comment: @theateist: Okay, I created [`example`](http://1drv.ms/1jJw1EH) (Visual Studio 2010). If it fit for you, I add this code to my answer.

Comment: It worked! My example also works if I remove `DataContext = this;` from `UserControl1`'s constructor and add `RealtiveSource`. So my question is why adding `DataContext = this;` without `RealtiveSource` doesn't work? Why I need `RealtiveSource` if I set `DataContext` and it should find `UCItems`?

Comment: Of course your labor was not in vain! I just want to understand, `UCItems` is not a dependency property but `UCItemsSource` is. It would be great if you could reference me to relevant article so I could understand.

Comment: I saw but I still don't understand why I need `RelativeSource` if I set `DataContext=this` in `UserControl1` constructor? Setting `DataContext` should allow me binding to `UCItems` like `DataContext.UCItems`. I'll appreciate  explanation or relevant article

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
private ObservableCollection<long> _windowCollection 
public ObservableCollection<long> WindowCollection 
{ 
   get { return _windowCollection; }
   set
   {
      _windowCollection = value;
      RaiseOnPropertyChange(() => WindowCollection);
   }
}
```