# Pass a ObservableCollection<object> to UserControl

Tags: wpf, collections, binding, dependencies

I have been trying to generalize the solution for passing ObservableCollection to a UserControl  provided here:

[How to bind collection dependency property in UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650599/how-to-bind-collection-dependency-property-in-usercontrol)

I changed the code behind UserControl to:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for myUserControl1.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class myUserControl1 : UserControl
{
    #region Public Section
    public ObservableCollection<object> UCItems
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    #endregion
    public myUserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        UCItems = new ObservableCollection<object>();
    }

    #region UCItemsSource Property

    public static readonly DependencyProperty UCItemsSourceProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("UCItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(myUserControl1));

    public IEnumerable UCItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(UCItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UCItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

and changed TexBox to DataGrid in  xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="OCasDPdemo.myUserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OCasDPdemo"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UCItemsSource, 
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                                   AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UCItemsSource.Person}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

I populate the collection in a similar way to the original example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> WindowCollection
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = this;


        var bob = new Person { FirstName = "Bob", LastName = "Brown", Age = 32.1, ID = 101 };
        var jim = new Person { FirstName = "Jim", LastName = "Green", Age = 21.0, ID = 201 };
        var mel = new Person { FirstName = "Mel", LastName = "Black", Age = 20, ID = 111 };

        WindowCollection = new ObservableCollection<Person>() {bob, jim, mel };
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var sue = new Person { FirstName = "Sue", LastName = "White", Age = 64.7, ID = 101 };
        var ted = new Person { FirstName = "Ted", LastName = "Grey", Age = 18.3, ID = 191 };

        WindowCollection.Add(sue);
        WindowCollection.Add(ted);
    }
}
```

and MainWindow xaml is:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <local:myUserControl1 UCItemsSource="{Binding Path=WindowCollection}" />
        <Button Content="Refresh" Click="Button_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I am getting empty lines (same as the number of persons) instead of grid with columns. This setup works with native types like long and string types (with TextBox). Could somebody please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The dependency property on the control is largely pointless. The itemssource can bind to a viewmodel's property in it's datacontext.

Comment: Unclear what you actually want. How is `Person` declared? Why do you think it makes sense for a `Person` object to be bound to `DataGrid.ItemsSource`? Is a `Person` actually a source of items? I.e. enumerable, collection, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this out myself, but the problem seems to be in your `myUserControl1` XAML.

Just inside the root `Grid` is an `ItemsControl` with the `ItemsSource` bound to `UCItemsSource`. This means the `ItemsControl` will generate one `ContentPresenter` for each element in that collection- which in your case will be your list of `Person`s.

Now, inside each of those `ContentPresenter`s, an instance of your `DataTemplate` will be created. Your `DataTemplate` contains a `DataGrid`. This means you will get one entire `DataGrid` per `Person`.

If instead you are trying to have one `DataGrid` with one row per `Person`, you might want something like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="OCasDPdemo.myUserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OCasDPdemo"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UCItemsSource, 
                                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                                                       AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
            
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: PERFECT! It now works as intended. Thank you very much. To clarify for the benefit of others, I was trying to prototype a user control which can work with ObservableCollection<Class> for any class by doing the binding in code. Keith Stein's solution takes me to one step closer. Keith, would you help me write the binding in code?

Comment: @I.Konuk What's wrong with the binding in `MainWindow`?

Comment: I thought it would give more flexibility as I could use variables for the object Type. But, thinking about it a bit more, the MainWindow container will be defined in xaml in most cases anyway. So there is no point. Thank you very much again for your prompt assistance.